# Removing Trailing White Spaces with python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have a script that loops over several search/replace regex in python, one of those operations is remove trailing spaces
I've tried:

```python
re.sub(r"""\s+$""", '', str)

re.sub(r""" +$""", r"""""", str)
```

and

```
re.sub(r""" +$""", r"""""", str, re.M)
```

I found several answers that simply recommended using `strip` my problem is that I want to integrate this in the regex replace mechanism.

Comment: Why all the triple-quotes? `r"\s+$"` would work fine.

Comment: Why do you want to integrate this into the regex replace mechanism? There is no obvious reason to do so.

Comment: @rmunn it's just to enforce that normal expression does not work, yours included, SlaterTyranus because I already have it and I don't want to move on line by line in a separate loop just to do so, and

Comment: @MysticOdin are you assigning the result of `sub` back to `str`? Otherwise `str` is never gonna change.

Comment: @m.buettner yes, the script works on all regexes in the dictionary except this one, I't actually in the middle of the dictionaries and entries before it and after had succeeded

Comment: @MysticOdin then we need to see the code that actually creates the regex and puts everything together. this should all work fine.

Comment: @MysticOdin wait, do you wanna do this for every line in a longer string? then you need to supply a `count` before passing in `re.M`. see my edited answer.

Comment: @m.buettner actually `count` is 0 if you did not pass it, output of `help(re.sub)` is `sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)`

Comment: @MysticOdin and what are you implying with that? that's why I passed `0` in the version of my answer, that doesn't skip `count`.

Comment: @m.buettner yes, I noticed that after the comment and accepted your answer :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The function is `sub` and takes the target string as an argument (and returns a modified copy):

```
str = re.sub(r'\s+$', '', str)
```

or if you want to remove trailing spaces from multiple lines in a single string, use one of these:

```
str = re.sub(r'\s+$', '', str, 0, re.M)
str = re.sub(r'\s+$', '', str, flags=re.M)
```

The `0` is the `count` parameter (where `0` means no limit) and then `re.M` makes `$` match at line endings. If you don't specify `flags` explicitly, you need that additional parameter, because `flags` is actually the fifth one.

Note that you only need triple quotes for multiline strings. What's important is the `r` for the pattern.

Alternatively, `rstrip` is used to remove trailing whitespace:

```
str = str.rstrip()
```

Comment: +1 for rstrip, definitely the right choice here. Any idea on how the performance of these two fare?

Comment: @MysticOdin still you need to supply the input string. otherwise, how is `re` gonna know which string to do the replacement on?

Comment: I understand that r strip is the correct choice for the simple remove trailing spaces, the problem is this script runs on files, and not line by line, and does several search/replace from an expression dictionary

Comment: the line in the script is something like `re.sub(Exp, RepExp, FileDump, re.M)` but it's inside a loop and I didn't want to share unnecessary code

Comment: @MysticOdin well it seems that code would have been necessary

Comment: @m.buettner: Nice debugging to finally spot the missing `count` parameter (well, not *missing* but clobbered by what was meant to be a flag)!  Very easy to miss.

Comment: This example removes multiple newlines.

Answer (score 1):

This removes trailing space using regex:

```
import os
import re
PATH = '/path/to/source'

re_strip = re.compile(r'[ \t]+(\n|\Z)')

for path, dirs, files in os.walk(PATH):
    for f in files:
        file_name, file_extension = os.path.splitext(f)
        if file_extension == '.py':
            path_name = os.path.join(path, f)
            with open(path_name, 'r') as fh:
                data = fh.read()

            data = re_strip.sub(r'\1', data)

            with open(path_name, 'w') as fh:
                fh.write(data)
```