# Regex to ignore only numbers tokens

Tags: python, regex

I am looking for a regex that ignore tokens that are numbers only. Please take a look at the following examples and see what I would like to achieve:

```
"token 88" -> "token 88"  
"token88"  -> "token88"  
"88"       -> ""  
"88token"  -> "88token"  
"88 token" -> "88 token"  
"token  "  -> "token" (remove additional spaces before and after token)
```

I succeeded creating a regex that catch the "88" example with the following:

```
/^\d+$/
```

if I could do a NOT operator and catch all the other tokens it would be great

Comment: is your input always have  only `number` which you want to omit. or they are mixed but starts from `number` always

Comment: If you want to remove trailing whitespace, [use `rstrip`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17350752/removing-trailing-white-spaces-with-python).

Comment: Try This:      
[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/fs73XqXlSORIggVc)

Comment: if the token contains only number in it I want the regex to ignore it. It can be a lot of cases of different tokens